# Convert Hex num in a File to ASCII

Tags: c++, c, hex, ascii

I have a file which I have to open using fopen. Now the issue with the file is its a hex file so when I open it I see the Hex numbers for example RG is 5247. Now when I read the file using (`fgets(line, sizeof(line), fd`)

```
line[0] is 5
line[1] is 2
line[2] is 4
line[4] is 7.
```

`52` is the hex for `char R` and `47` is the hex for `char G`. I want to obtain that. I know I can use a lookuptable and this will work, but I was looking for a more different solutions. Have tried a lot but to no avail.

Please help!!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hex file".

Comment: this is a hex file. its a flash file that goes onto a micro.

Comment: @KerrekSB, He means it's literally an intel hex record, I think.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I have to agree with OP, we've always called [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) hex files.

Comment: yes its an intel hex record file.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that - perhaps you could edit the post to make it clear that you're talking about a specific file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each pair of ASCII-encoded hexadecimal digits into a character.

Something like this:

```
   unsigned int high = line[0] - 0x30;
   if (high > 9)
      high -= 7;
   unsigned int low  = line[1] - 0x30;
   if (low > 9)
      low -= 7;
   char c = (char) ((high << 4) | low);
```

Of course, you can optimize the code above, and you'll have to write a loop over the characters in the variable "line".

Also, if lower case letters are used, first they'll have to be converted to upper case. Like

```
unsigned char ch = line[0];
if (islower(ch))
   ch = toupper(ch);
unsigned int high = ch - 0x30;
if (high > 9)
   high -= 7;
etc
```

Comment: @Carl Norum: I guess it's a matter of choice. If you're working wih hexadecimal digits you won't have problems with 0x30.

Comment: @CarlNorum Because its an ASCII HEX file, and thus the math requires you use the *byte value* of an ASCII '0', which is 0x30. Run this code on a non-ASCII platform (such as an OS/390 or AS/400 IBM platform as an example, which is [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)) and the literal character encoding for `'0'` is *not* 0x30, thus your code will be incorrect. As much as I hate hard-codes, for multi-platform compatibility processing a well-defind source file type, its somewhat necessary.

Comment: That's true- I didn't think of a potential file format/system character set incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

- convert hex to int
- convert result to char similar to `char res = (char)intValue;`

code:

```
// this works if the string chars are only  0-9, A-F 
// because of implemented mapping in `hex_to_int`

int hex_to_int(char c){
        int first = c / 16 - 3;//    1st is dec 48 = char 0
        int second = c % 16; //      10 in 1st16  5 in 2nd 16
        // decimal code of ascii char 0-9:48-57  A-E: 65-69
        // omit dec 58-64:  :,;,<,=,>,?,@
        // map first or second 16 range to 0-9 or 10-15
        int result = first*10 + second; 
        if(result > 9) result--;
        return result;
}

int hex_to_ascii(char c, char d){
        int high = hex_to_int(c) * 16;
        int low = hex_to_int(d);
        return high+low;
}

int main(){
        const char* st = "48656C6C6F3B";
        int length = strlen(st);
        int i;
        char buf = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
                if(i % 2 != 0){
                        printf("%c", hex_to_ascii(buf, st[i]));
                }else{
                        buf = st[i];
                }
        }
}
```

output:

> Hello;
>
> RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 59ms)

Answer (score 0):

I just read a small hex file and following *C++* code worked as per your need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<deque>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>

char val(const std::string& s)
{
    int x;   
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << s;
    ss >> x;
    return static_cast<char> (x);
}

int main()
{

std::deque<char> deq;

char ch;
std::string s;

std::ifstream fin("input.hex");

while (fin >> std::skipws >> ch) {
    if(ch != ':') //Hex file begins with ':'
      deq.push_back(ch);
    if(deq.size() ==2)
    {
      s.push_back(deq.front());
      deq.pop_front();

      s.push_back(deq.front());
      deq.pop_front();

      std::cout<< s<<":"<<val(s)<<std::endl;;
      s.clear();
    }
}

 fin.close() ;

 return 0;
}
```